# Batch look up Year and Month for folder

Tags: batch-file

Hello I have batch code which zips my folder and removes the original copy. I run this as a task scheduler every month. There is one thing I been having problems with. My code is base on this on this variable on the top of my batch code call "set FILETOZIP" ... Is there a way where I can use another variable to look up the current month and year on my machine ? [ Rest of my batch code ] works find and I do not need any help with it.

Current :

```
set FILETOZIP=D:\Farm\201411

[Rest of code ]
```

Expected Code :

```
set FIND_YEAR_MONTH=" some date formula " 
set FILETOZIP=D:\Farm\"A way to set FIND_YEAR_MONTH here "
[Rest of code ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Time settings independent:

```
@Echo Off


Call :GetDate.Init
Rem :GetDate.Init should be called one time in the code before call to :Getdate
Call :GetDate


set YEAR_MONTH=FINANCE%year%%month%
set file_to_zip=D:\Farm\%YEAR_MONTH%
[Rest of code ] 



Goto :EOF

:GetDate.Init
Set /A "jan=1,feb=2,mar=3,apr=4,may=5,jun=6,jul=7,aug=8,sep=9,oct=10,nov=11,dec=12"
Set /A "mon=1,tue=2,wed=3,thu=4,fri=5,sat=6,sun=7"
(
Echo .Set InfHeader=""
Echo .Set InfSectionOrder=""
Echo .Set InfFooter="%%2"
Echo .Set InfFooter1=""
Echo .Set InfFooter2=""
Echo .Set InfFooter3=""
Echo .Set InfFooter4=""
Echo .Set Cabinet="OFF"
Echo .Set Compress="OFF"
Echo .Set DoNotCopyFiles="ON"
Echo .Set RptFileName="NUL"
) >"%Temp%\~foo.ddf"
Goto :Eof

:GetDate
Set "tf=%Temp%\~%random%"
Makecab /D InfFileName="%tf%" /F "%Temp%\~foo.ddf" >NUL
For /F "usebackq tokens=1-7 delims=: " %%a In ("%tf%") Do (
Set /A "year=%%g,month=%%b,day=1%%c-100,weekday=%%a"
Set /A "hour=1%%d-100,minute=1%%e-100,second=1%%f-100")
Del "%tf%" >NUL 2>&1
Goto :Eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set FILETOZIP=D:\Farm\20%date:~10,2%%date:~4,2%
```

Is your basic structure - you don't tell us your date format which can be set on a user-by-user basis.

Assuming your format is `Fri 11-21-14` then this picks the `10`th character (start counting at character 0) for 2, then the `4`th for 2. If your date-format differs, then adjust to suit.

Another way is

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%a in ("%date%") do set /a filetozip=20%%d*100+1%%b-100
set "filetozip=D:\Farm\%filetozip%"
```

Again, the formula here depends on your date-format. Using your date elements and the `delims` set shown, then a date like `Fri 11-21-14` would assign `Fri` to %%a, `11` to %%b, `21` to %%c and `14` to %%d. The mathematical gymnastics prefix the month and make it 100+the actual month number, so 100 needs to be subtracted. This is because batch treats numbers starting `0` as octal, so 08 and 09 are not valid. These become `108` and `109` - conveniently decimal.

Answer (score 0):

A solution independent of locale settings:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I
```

It will give you:

```
  20141121175755.279000+060 
( YYYYMMDDhhmmss.<fraction>+/-<timedifference to UTC>  )
```

from here, it is easy:

```
set datetime=%datetime:~0,6%
```

gives you  `201411`

and finally to get you pathname:

```
set "FILETOZIP=D:\Farm\%datetime%"
```